# Sharing in Salesforce Community

Tags: community, sharing, partner-communities, sharing-rule, custom-reports

I have a report based on a custom object X.
X has a lookup to Account.

The report is for Partner Community users. A commnunity user should only see the records of object X associated to the Account on their Contact.

I have set the External Sharing Setting of object X to Private. Now I want to create a new sharing rule to achieve the above.

Any idea how to do it? I'm new to Communities. Please help.

Comment: can you post your approach for creating sharing rule

Comment: @SantanuBoral I wanted to do something like `User:Contact.Account.Name = Account.Name of object X` in the criteria. And then share with partner roles. Is this possible at all?  I've not worked with this before.

Comment: Yes possible and compare with AccountId instead of name